# What's the performance impact of installing require-dev packages in a production application?

Tags: php, composer-php

If on the production site, I am also installing the dev packages via composer (i.e. those defined in `composer.json`'s `require-dev` section).

Given the PHP autoloading mechanism, is the performance overhead negligible?

Comment: use `--no-dev` on prod?

Comment: and also use `--optimize-autoloader`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not simply try it out and see what happens?

Comment: ....and additionally: why do you need dev packages on your production system? If they are neccessary to run your application, they should not be listed in `require-dev`

Comment: One may like or dislike the question, but there is nothing unclear about it, IMO.

Comment: To me, this is unclear in different points: why are dev packages needed on a prod system? How many of those are in place (having a few might not cause any overhead, having more, probably with different namespace configurations, might be different)? Also, the used PHP version and configuration might differ - and after all, benchmarking this should not be hard to come to any conclusion

Comment: Also, if such packages are installed, the whole application might behave different (for example, if `class_exists` within the application is used to detect dev classes)

Comment: @Nico the question is not about "why install these packages" or "should I do this", the question is very clearly about "performance impact". The other points are moot, since installation of any (dev or no dev) package would not have no noticeable performance impact. It's the use of the packages what could cause that, which is beyond the scope of the question (and yes, that would require many more details).

Answer (score 2):

Just for *installing* the packages, there should be almost no runtime performance impact, if any at all (as long as the application you are running avoids using any of the "dev" packages while running on "production" mode, as for example Symfony does).

But you'd increase the [attack surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_surface) for your application, making it potentially more vulnerable to security issues in those packages. Just for being installed, an unforeseen vulnerability or misconfiguration in any of those packages can make your whole system vulnerable.

Basically, do not install anything in production that's not needed to run the application. The less code there is, the less likely an unexpected bug could come to say "hi!".

And if your production code does actually depend on those `require-dev` packages, then you'd have to admit those are not really "dev" packages for you, but hard dependencies for the application. Better move them (after careful examination, since "dev" packages may make some security assumptions that are not true on a production system) from `require-dev` to `require`.